# Mono.Cecil add an internal class

Tags: mono.cecil

I want to add an inner class using Mono.Cecil

```
public class MyClass
{
private class InternalClass
{

}
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

```
internalType = new TypeDefinition(
                "", "InternalClass",
                TypeAttributes.NestedPrivate,
                module.Import(typeof(object)));

type.NestedTypes.Add(internalType);
```